# How can I write boolean operators in a class that has pointers of the same class?

Tags: c++

I have a class that helps to represents arithmetic expressions in AST, it looks like this:

```
class ExpNode {
    public:
    tokentype token;
    std::string opname = " ";
    std::string name;
    char op;
    double value;
    bool visited = false;
    ExpNode* left;
    ExpNode* right;

    ExpNode() {}
    ExpNode( tokentype token ) {this->token = token;}

    bool operator==(const ExpNode& rhs) const{
        // this part assume that the right and left children
        // are the same in the two expression tree
        if(left->token == rhs.left->token){
            if(right->token == rhs.right->token){
                if(left->token == constant){
                    if(left->value != rhs.left->value) return false;
                }else if(left->token == input){
                    if(left->name != rhs.left->name) return false;
                }else if(left->token == operation){
                    // here i'm not sure that, this could recall the function again
                    // if(left->left != rhs.left->left || left->right != rhs.left->right) return false;
                }
                if(right->token == constant){
                    if(right->value != rhs.right->value) return false;
                }else if(right->token == input){
                    if(right->name != rhs.right->name) return false;
                }else if(right->token == operation){
                    // if(right->left != rhs.right->left || right->right != rhs.right->right) return false;
                }
            return true;
            }
        // this part assume that the right and left children
        // are swapped in the two expression tree, but they're the same
        }else if(left->token == rhs.right->token){
            if(right->token == rhs.left->token){
                if(left->token == constant){
                    if(left->value != rhs.right->value) return false;
                }else if(left->token == input){
                    if(left->name != rhs.right->name) return false;
                }else if(left->token == operation){
                    // if(left->left != rhs.right->left || left->right != rhs.right->right) return false;
                }
                if(right->token == constant){
                    if(right->value != rhs.left->value) return false;
                }else if(right->token == input){
                    if(right->name != rhs.left->name) return false;
                }else if(right->token == operation){
                    // if(right->left != rhs.left->left || right->right != rhs.left->right) return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I want this bool `operator==()` to use for common subexpression elimination. My question is that the commented parts of the bool `operator==()` is capable to call this function again and give back a good return, or what do you suggest to compare these classes?

Comment: Please clarify what your question is. The current wording is quite unclear. _"My question is that the commented parts of the bool operator==() is capable to call this function again"_ is not a question as written, and _"give back a good return"_ does not explain what a good or bad result would be. You could explain what the current result is, versus what you want it to be.

Comment: Are you worried about infinite recursion?  As long as your data structure doesn't have any cycles, (which it shouldn't, since it is a tree,) you shouldn't have any problem calling into the `operator==` of the pointers `left` and `right`.

Comment: i'm just not sure that operator== could work in itself on a pointer that has the same class, so you say that this could be ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator `==` is implemented for your `class` and the exact source-code commented out will not call the function again, since you are using the `!=` operator. `foo != bar` invokes the `!=` operator, and not the `==` operator. However, if you use `!(foo == bar)` instead of `foo != bar`, then you are referring the `==` operator and if both `foo` and `bar` are `ExpNode` instances, then the exact same function will be called. If you intend to call the `==` operator, using the `!=` operator, then you should implement he `!=` operator, like this:

```
bool operator!=(const ExpNode& rhs) const{
    return !(this == rhs);
}
```

Comment: Note that this pattern can be used for every collection of operators a-b <==> a+(-b); or a<b <==> !(a>=b) etc.